# Copy Chrome Html in nice format

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How do I copy the whole Chrome Dom Tree with Ctrl Shift I? Right now when I copy, it copies in a single, bad formatted line format.
I want to copy, while keeping tabs, tree format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which tab of the developers tools are you copying from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the dev tools, go to the Elements page, right click the root node (probably the `html` node), hover over "Copy", and when the sub-menu opens, click "Copy outerHTML", and paste it into whatever you are pasting it into. You will have the complete HTML of the page.

Alternatively, press Ctrl+U to view the source HTML for the page and copy that.